# How to get vim to indent once when entering a newline inside brackets

Tags: vim

One thing that has been annoying me a lot in vim is if I enter a new line inside pair of brackets, it automatically inserts 2 (8 spaces):

```
x = {

        }

y = [

        ]

z = (

        )
```

I'm unsure how to change this so it only enters one indent (4 spaces). Furthermore, I would like is so the closing bracket isn't indented at all when I enter a new line like this:

```
x = {

}
```

My vimrc: https://pastebin.com/sYQ55W9m

Comment: You should better share your vimrc also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've figured it out. This configuration seems to give me what I want:

```
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set smarttab
set autoindent
set cindent
filetype indent off
```

Comment: It is better to keep tabsstop as 8 as you have softtabstop as 4. Also I prefer filetype indent on

Comment: @dlmeetei I found that having filetype indent on caused my issue

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the option smartindent. According to Vim Help :

> An indent is automatically inserted:
>     - After a line ending in '{'.
>     - After a line starting with a keyword from 'cinwords'.
>     - Before a line starting with '}'

Personally I use [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) instead of vim-autoclose, in case you want the new line like this :

```
x = {

}
```

Comment: I've disabled it, but it is still happening